# mysql: Is mysqladmin -p create equivalent to create database?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql administration and I need to setup certain program. At some point, the installation guide states to execute this command:

```
mysqladmin -p create somedatabasename
```

Is this equivalent to `create database somedatabasename` ?

So far I have checked the documentation and I think both commands are equivalent but I don't want to screw my existing databases. Can someone confirm?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/database-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and with the  `-p` argument it should prompt you for a password to authenticate to perform the correlated command operation.

> [**mysqladmin**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)
>   supports the following commands. Some of the commands take an argument
>   following the command name.
>
> - `create db_name`
>
> Create a new database named **db_name**.
>
> - `--password[=password], -p[password]`
>
> The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the
>   short option form (`-p`), you *cannot* have a space between the option
>   and the password. If you omit the password value following the
>   `--password` or `-p` option on the command line,
>   [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)
>   prompts for one.
>
> <sub>[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html)</sub>